# Partitioning BigQuery table, loaded from AVRO

Tags: google-bigquery, avro, partitioning

I have a bigquery table whose data is loaded from AVRO files on GCS. This is NOT an external table.

One of the fields in every AVRO object is `created` (date with a `long` type) and I'd like to use this field to partition the table.

What is the best way to do this?

Thanks

Comment: Why is AVRO important? Is this a federated table in GCS, or is this statement of the question true: "This is NOT an external table" ?

Answer (score 1):

Two issues that prevent from using `created` as a partition column:

- *The avro file defines the schema during loading time*. There is only one option to partition at this step: select Partition By Ingestion Time, however, most probably will include another field for this purpose.
- *The field created is long*. This value seems to contain a Datetime. If it was Integer you will be able to use Integer Range partitioned tables somehow. But in this case, you would need to convert the long value into a Date/Timestamp to use [date/timestamp partitioned tables](http://date/timestamp%20partitioned%20tables).

So, from my opinion you can try:

1. Importing the data as it is into a first table.
2. Create a second empty table partitioned by `created` of type TIMESTAMP.
3. Execute a query reading from the first table and applying a timestamp function on `created` like [TIMESTAMP_SECONDS](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/functions-and-operators#timestamp_seconds) (or TIMESTAMP_MILLIS) to transform the value to a TIMESTAMP, so each value you insert will be partioned.